# JavaFX : Use an Indeterminate Progressbar in a splashScreen

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, splash-screen

I have a splash screen :

[image: splash screen]
I need to have the animation of the progress bar (Indeterminate) but it doesn't work.

It's maybe due to because my thread is running in my initilize methode.

```
public class splashscreenController implements Initializable {
  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    new SplashScreen().run();
  }

  class SplashScreen extends Task {
    @Override
    public Object call() {

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
                Parent root = null;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../gui/NewUI.fxml"));
                } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

                assert root != null;
                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 720);
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
                MainJavaFx.setPrimaryStage(stage);
                ((Stage) panParent.getScene().getWindow()).close();
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Example](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2305098) of a JavaFX splash screen with progress bar monitoring Task progress.  Note, critically, that the `Task` is run in its own thread: `new Thread(friendTask).start()`.  To make it indefinite, just don't bind the progress bar's progress property to the task's progress property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your code:

```
new SplashScreen().run();
```

A `Task` does not provide functionality for running on a new thread. `run` is executed on the calling thread.

```
class SplashScreen extends Task {
    @Override
    public Object call() {

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // placeholder for parts of your code
                longRunningOperation();
                guiUpdate();
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}
```

Even if you execute this task on a seperate thread, the `Runnable` passed to `Platfrom.runLater` is executed on the JavaFX application thread and doing long-running operations from this runnable freezes the GUI.

Do all the long-running operations on the background thread instead and only do short updates using `Platfrom.runLater`.

```
new Thread(new SplashScreen()).start();
```

```
class SplashScreen extends Task {
    @Override
    public Object call() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        final Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../gui/NewUI.fxml"));

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 720);
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
                MainJavaFx.setPrimaryStage(stage);
                ((Stage) panParent.getScene().getWindow()).close();
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note that since you're not using the functionality provided by `Task`, you could simply implement `Runnable` with your class instead of inheriting from `Task`.

Comment: So if I understand, my code is wrong because I need to stop my thread before the runLater. thank you now it works !

Comment: @charlesLgn *"I need to stop the thread before"* That's not really the case. Everything that matters is that operations on the javafx application thread complete fast (withing a few ms at most). `Platform.runLater` results in code being run on the javafx application thread, so `Thread.sleep` is something you need to avoid doing in the runnable. The background thread can keep running for as long as you like after using `Platform.runLater`.